# Combining two conditions in one LINQ query

Tags: c#, linq

I was wondering if there is a way to combine two conditions on two different column in one LINQ query?

I have got a books table -> tbl_books which have three columns

id - pk

subject_id - fk to tbl_subjects

book_summary - book summary details

var book_ids = list of distinct book_ids

var subject_ids = list of distinct subject_ids

```
//This will return books for the provided book_ids
var books1 = db.tbl_books.where(b=> book_ids.contains(b.id)).ToList();

//This will return books for the provided subject_ids
var books2 = db.tbl_books.where(b=>subject_ids.contains(b.subject_id)).ToList();
```

Is there a way to combine both the queries into one query?

I know I can do this:

```
db.tbl_books.where(b=> book_ids.contains(b.id)).Union(db.tbl_books.where(b=>subject_ids.contains(b.subject_id))).ToList();
```

P.S.
I don't want to get all the rows from tbl_books at the start

Could you please suggest a solution to this problem. Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take a tour at https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 1):

You can use `||` in place of `Union`:

```
db.tbl_books
  .Where(b => book_ids.contains(b.id) || 
              subject_ids.contains(b.subject_id)))
  .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
var selectedBooks = db.tbl_books.where(b=> book_ids.contains(b.id) || subject_ids.contains(b.subject_id)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 var query = (from a in db.tbl_books 
 where a.book_ids == b_id && a.subject_ids == sub_id 
 select new{
      a.[column_name],
      a.[column_name],
      a.[column_name],
      //columns you want to retrieve
 }).ToList();
```

or

```
 var query = (from a in db.tbl_books 
 where a.book_ids == b_id || a.subject_ids == sub_id 
 select new{
      a.[column_name],
      a.[column_name],
      a.[column_name],
      //columns you want to retrieve
 }).ToList();
```

Depends on what you're trying to accomplish. Hope it helps you.